# Validate a statement from string in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string;

```
String allIn = "(50 > 100) AND (85< 100)";
```

Now I need to evaluate if the conditions inside are TRUE or FALSE, how can I do it?

In real the string will be a value from a field in my DB, where I will substitute different values and they will form a string as shown above.

Comment: describe the full set of operations you want to support. Are ">" and "<" are the only operations? Is there a possibility that invalid data is present?

Comment: The possible are  < > AND OR != it is possible for invalid data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [eval project](https://eval.dev.java.net/)

Comment: I just glanced at it, but it looks like that only supports Java syntax, so he'd have to convert what he's using (SQL-ish?) to Java.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a "Compiler Design" question where you:

- Parse the string into it's individual components using space, < > AND OR != as delimeters
- Push on to the stack when you encounter a value
- Pop from the stack when you encounter an operator and get next part of expression

But personally - I would go down the Eval route (as stated already) if at all possible - even if it means that you have to change the current syntax of the string or parse and convert the syntax:

https://eval.dev.java.net/